# Adding objects with relations to realm database from json?

Tags: json, realm

I have RealmObjects with relations amongst other fields:

```
class A extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey
    private int idA;
    private B objB;
}

class B extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey
    private int idB;
    private String foo;
}
```

I would like now to initialize them using the `createAllFromJson()` function.
How can I reference `objB` in json?

**EDIT:**
I figured it out: the function to use is `createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` :)

I was just hoping to put the primary key of B in the Json to create A (`[{idA:0, objB:42}]`) but this gives me the exception that idB is an int and cannot be converted to a JsonObject.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{idA:0, objB: { id:"42"}]
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "objB" : {
        "field_a" : 0,
        "filed_b" : "something"
    }
}
```

Comment: The problema with this is that with objects A refering to the same B and/or a more interleaved model structure this would result in a high redundency. Because this data comes over the network this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: @moritz In that case, you have to have a `@PrimaryKey` defined in the `objB`, then Realm will try to update the object with the same `@PrimaryKey`. Without the pk defined, there will be no way to tell whether you want to create a new object or update an existing one.

Comment: I already had primary keys. But I solved it, was using the wrong method, see my edit